# Is there an R function to count values separated by semi-colon in a column and across rows

Tags: r

I am wondering if there is a smart way to count the occurrence of values separated by semi-colon in a column and across the entire rows.

#### Sample data and output expected

[image: sample data and output expected]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a `tidyverse` approach:

```
library(tidyverse)

# example data
df1 = data.frame(var1 = c(2,4,3,5),
                 var2 = c("3;5;2;0;1","2;3;8;5","9;6;2","8;5;4;7;0;1"),
                 stringsAsFactors = F)

df1 %>%
  separate_rows(var2) %>%         # split values to different rows
  filter(var2 %in% df1$var1) %>%  # keep values that match var1
  count(var2)                     # count each value

# # A tibble: 4 x 2
#   var2      n
#   <chr> <int>
# 1 2         3
# 2 3         2
# 3 4         1
# 4 5         3
```

And a base R approach:

```
v = unlist(strsplit(df1$var2, ";"))
data.frame(table(v[v %in% df1$var1]))

#   Var1 Freq
# 1    2    3
# 2    3    2
# 3    4    1
# 4    5    3
```